# Symfony2: 3rd party bundle is not available in my bundle config.yml

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, state-machine

### The Issue

Why is the winzou (3rd party) configuration not available to my config.yml inside a bundle?

It throws 'There is no extension able to load the configuration winzou...'

### Updates

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/prepend_extension.html

Looks like this is the end result I want to happen - to be treated like its prepended/appended to the app config.yml.
I can load the file and prepend it..  but I feel the fact symfony already allows loading of additional configs per bundle.. there must be a simpler way to load it.

---

I load winzou state machine bundle:
*/app/AppKernel.php*

```
new winzou\Bundle\StateMachineBundle\winzouStateMachineBundle(),
```

Then I am loading a config from inside my bundle (OrderBundle).
*/src/OrderBundle/DependencyInjection/OrderExtension.php*

```
class OrderExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('config.yml');
    }
}
```

If I put the statemachine config inside the OrderBundle config:
*/src/OrderBundle/Resources/config/config.yml*

```
winzou_state_machine:
    order_state_machine:
    ...
```

An Exception is thrown:

```
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "winzou_state_machine" (in [...]/OrderBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/config.yml). Looked for namespace "winzou_state_machine", found none
```

It is fine if I place the state machine configuration in the root app folders.
*/app/config/config.yml*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because the bundle extension's load method responsibility to load service configuration related to the bundle it belongs to and only for that. The container you get as the argument of the load method is just a copy of the app container, it does not contains everything (only just parameters) [[#using-the-load-method]](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#using-the-load-method).

> Using the load() Method
>
> In the load() method, all services and parameters related to this extension will be loaded. This method doesn't get the actual container instance, but a copy. This container only has the parameters from the actual container. After loading the services and parameters, the copy will be merged into the actual container, to ensure all services and parameters are also added to the actual container.

As you said you can use the prepend method to provide a sensible default configuration for other bundles and ease the use of yours [[prepend_extension]](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/prepend_extension.html).